# trying to read a file on a server from html page and java script

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">   
<html xmlns ="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">        
<head>    
    <title>first_demo</title>     
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    //ajax call 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "hostname/filename.txt",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <p>click to on </p>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Your script needs to be in the `head`  or just before `</body>` 2) are there any errors in the console resulting from your AJAX request?

Comment: no it is not throwing any error, and i tried to put script inside the head .. but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns ="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    

<head>

<title> first_demo </title>

</head>
<body>
<p>click to on </p>

 <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />
 <!--your ajax script comes here-->
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "hostname/filename.txt",//your url here
            data: {
                 //Additional data
            },  
            dataType: 'html/text',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("success: " + response);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log("error: " + response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am not still not able to open the file on the server.
let suppose my server name is: testing_server. 
i created index.html with above code and put it in web folder of testing_server.
in ajax call: url: "http://testing_server/on.txt" so i am hosting my page on same server only.

Can you please help in this??

Comment: What server are you using? IIS, apache ? And did you make sure that the file is not read only? Have you tried pressing F12 and opening developer tools and see what your request / response in the browser is?